# TypeScript infers never type but requires assignment

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

In my project I have a class that acts as a generic type for files. Depending on which file type we're treating it should expose additional properties.

I tried to achieve this with conditional types that default to `never` to "hide" the property. However, when I try tu use the class, the type checker complains that I am missing the property that has been inferred to be of type `never`. Of course, I can't assign it, so I am left with an object that is impossible to create.

The error happens all the way on the bottom of this block of code:

```
// just for convenience
type MP4OptionsT = {
    codec?: 'h264',
    profile: 'baseline' | 'main' | 'high',
    bitrate: number,
};

// this is the class in question
class MediaFile<Format extends 'mp4' | 'png'> {
    public path: string;
    public format: Format extends 'mp4' ? 'mp4' : Format extends 'png' ? 'png' : never;    // once the generic type argument is set, this can only be a specific string literal

    // this should not have to be assigned if generic type argument is 'png'
    public mp4Options: Format extends 'mp4' ? MP4OptionsT : never;

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
        format: Format extends 'mp4' ? 'mp4' : Format extends 'png' ? 'png' : never;
        // this should not have to be assigned if generic type argument is 'png' - however it demands to be assigned
        mp4Options: Format extends 'mp4' ? MP4OptionsT : never,
    }) {
        this.path = opts.path;
        this.format = opts.format;
        this.mp4Options = opts.mp4Options;
    }
}

// this is OK
const mp4File = new MediaFile<'mp4'>({
    path: '/some/file/somewhere.mp4',
    format: 'mp4',
    mp4Options: {
        profile: 'high',
        bitrate: 1000,
    }
});

// the type checker complains about this: "Property mp4Otions is missing in type {...}".
// if I explicitly include mp4Options, the type checker notes that "Type any is not assignable to Type never" - which makes sense, but precludes this class from ever being instantiated.
const pngFile = new MediaFile<'png'>({
    path: '/some/file/somewhere.png',
    format: 'png',    // since there is exactly one option for this, it would be nice if it were implicitly set...
});
```

From my understanding of the section Conditional Types of this page http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html it seems like mp4Options should just be able to be "not there" once it has been evaluated to be of type `never`.
As ab experiment, I also tried having it fall back to undefined. This worked if I manually assigned `mp4Options: undefined`, otherwise the type checker still complained about missing properties. This should definitely not be the case, I think, as we can omit properties that are `undefined` out of the box (without conditional type).

Is there a workaround or less convoluted way of doing this? Or do I simply have an error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better served by using a common base class for the `MediaFile` and derive two separate classes for the `mp4` and `png` formats.

If you do want to go down the single class with conditional magic route, we can do it. Although conditional types can't impact the optionality of the property as you want to do, we can combine them with intersection types to get the desired effect:

```
// just for convenience
type MP4OptionsT = {
    codec?: 'h264',
    profile: 'baseline' | 'main' | 'high',
    bitrate: number,
};
type FormatOptions<F extends 'mp4' | 'png'> = (F extends 'mp4' ? { mp4Options: MP4OptionsT } : { mp4Options?: never})

class MediaFile<Format extends 'mp4' | 'png'> {
    public path: string;
    public format: Format // no need for a conditional type here, it the same type as Format

    public mp4Options: FormatOptions<Format>['mp4Options'];

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
        format: Format,
    } &  FormatOptions<Format>)
    {
        this.path = opts.path;
        this.format = opts.format;
        this.mp4Options = opts.mp4Options;
    }
}

// this is OK, no need for explicit type arguments
const mp4File = new MediaFile({
    path: '/some/file/somewhere.mp4',
    format: 'mp4',
    mp4Options: {
        profile: 'high',
        bitrate: 1000,
    }
});
mp4File.mp4Options.bitrate // ok 

// no need for the type argument 
const pngFile = new MediaFile({
    path: '/some/file/somewhere.png',
    format: 'png', // no need for mp4Options
});
pngFile.mp4Options.codec // error
```

Comment: Thank you! I did think about going with the shared base class solution but ran into similar problems there (plus some issues with integrating it into the existing code).
However with these pointers, I think I may be able to refactor the current state of my project into something workable.

Comment: @JanHettenkofer If you have issues with the shared base ask and we shall answer ;-)

Comment: The problem was that I had the `options` property in the base class as well as the constructor for it. The overriding classes didn't change the constructor at all, only the type of the property. It now is very clear to me why this didn't work (the inheriting constructor still expects an `unknown` option member), I guess I just didn't have enough tea before ;-). I changed things around a bit and I think this will be a bit more readable (with less magic, as you correctly pointed out).
I will add the shared base class approach as an answer tomorrow once it's cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a direct answer to my question, but an attempt to write a more readable solution. Titian Cernicova-Dragomir has already provided a very good example of how to do what I had originally asked for.*

After playing around some more, I came up with this solution which avoids the complicated type inference that I was asking about in my original question:

```
type LegalFormatT = 'mp4' | 'png' | 'jpg';

type FormatOptions<F extends LegalFormatT> = F extends 'mp4' ? { options: MP4OptionsT } : F extends 'png' ? { options: PNGOptionsT } : { options?: never };

type MP4OptionsT = {
    codec?: 'h264',
    profile: 'baseline' | 'main' | 'high',
    bitrate: number,
};

type PNGOptionsT = {
    sequence: boolean,
};

class MediaFile<Format extends LegalFormatT> {
    public path: string;
    public format: Format;

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
        format: Format,
    }) {
        this.path = opts.path;
        this.format = opts.format;
    }
}

class MP4MediaFile extends MediaFile<'mp4'> {
    public options: FormatOptions<'mp4'>['options'];

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
        options: MP4OptionsT,
    }) {
        super({
            path: opts.path,
            format: 'mp4',
        });
        this.options = opts.options;
    }
}

class PNGMediaFile extends MediaFile<'png'> {
    public options: FormatOptions<'png'>['options'];

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
        options: PNGOptionsT,
    }) {
        super({
            path: opts.path,
            format: 'png',
        });
        this.options = opts.options;
    }
}

class JPGMediaFile extends MediaFile<'jpg'> {
    public options: FormatOptions<'jpg'>['options'];

    constructor(opts: {
        path: string,
    }) {
        super({
            path: opts.path,
            format: 'jpg',
        });
    }
}
```

While I really love to use all the type inference features TypeScript has to offer, I think in this case it's preferable to "kill my darling" and do some more manual work to avoid driving some future maintainer to panic.

Thanks a lot to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir for the answer to the actual question and motivation to follow the "classic" extended base class route.